# Count of the icon tab filter

Tags: count, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I would really like to understand how to use the "count" property of the IconTabFilter for SAPUI5 to dynamically show the count of the result set of a table.

I have the following code -

`<IconTabFilter 
    count="{DataSet/$count}">
     <Table items="{DataSet}">`

But the count is not filled automatically.

I am using an oData model that is bound on the view level. I do not want to make another backend request just for the counts. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a different mechanism that can be used?

I also tried using the updateFinished event on the table to then get the count and set it via JS but the event is triggered only on DOM placement of the table. In my case the table is hidden behind the IconTab and is not placed into the DOM till the first time the user clicks the tab so its useless.

Really would appreciate some insight into how to use this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so what I did was I bound my information to a local model and did an oData $expand query to fetch the entire pages information in one call.

This worked out for me because I had several sets of data to be fetched. Before they were bound individually to tables, now they are all in one query.

In the .done() method of the call I just used the setCount method of the IconTabFilter to set the count as per the return data set.

Comment: @NathanielFlick 

Okay, this was some years ago already but what I did in a nut shell was -

`oData.read("/Dataset", {
   expand: "this, that, otherthing", 
   success: function(oResultSet){ 
      that.oIconTabBar.setCount(oResultSet.results.that.length);
   }
}`

Comment: Multi line comment replies aren't allowed, so the formatting stays as it is :|